# Using groovy Eval to process generated expression

Tags: groovy, eval

I'm trying to create a field mapping to map fields from user-friendly names to member variables in a variety of domain objects. The larger context is that I'm building up an ElasticSearch query based on user-constructed rules stored in a database, but for the sake of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
class MyClass {
  Integer amount = 123
}

target = new MyClass()
println "${target.amount}"

fieldMapping = [
  'TUITION' : 'target.amount'
]

fieldName = 'TUITION'
valueSource = '${' + "${fieldMapping[fieldName]}" + '}'
println valueSource

value = Eval.me('valueSource')
```

The Eval fails. Here's the output:

```
123
${target.amount}
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: valueSource for class: Script1
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: valueSource for class: Script1
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at t.run(t.groovy:17)
```

What's necessary to evaluate the generated variable name and return the value `123`? It seems like the real problem is that it's not recognizing that `valueSource` has been defined, not the actual expression held in `valueSource`, but that could be wring, too.

Comment: I thought `evaluate()` might work, but that's just for scripts, and doesn't work in the context of a grails app.

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) for Eval. The methods are not aware of the scope you are calling them from. To make `valueSource` available you'd have to call `Eval.me` with `symbol` and `object` or call one of the `x`/`xy`/`xyz` methods.

Comment: I've been looking at the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need to use a slightly different mechanism: the `GroovyShell`. You can instantiate a `GroovyShell` and use it to evaluate a `String` as a script, returning the result. Here's your example, modified to work properly:

```
class MyClass {
    Integer amount = 123
}

target = new MyClass()

fieldMapping = [
        'TUITION' : 'target.amount'
]
fieldName = 'TUITION'

// These are the values made available to the script through the Binding
args = [target: target]

// Create the shell with the binding as a parameter
shell = new GroovyShell(args as Binding)

// Evaluate the "script", which in this case is just the string "target.amount".
// Inside the shell, "target" is available because you added it to the shell's binding.
result = shell.evaluate(fieldMapping[fieldName])

assert result == 123
assert result instanceof Integer
```